# Text file formats on Mac

Tags: macos, text-editors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text editor for Mac that will open any file](https://superuser.com/questions/27507/text-editor-for-mac-that-will-open-any-file)

On Windows the most popular text formats are DOC, RTF and TXT. What text formats are Mac users using? Is there another popular text format?

Which are the most popular text editors on Mac?

Comment: Not a duplicate! RTF / RTFD is pretty much the native rich text format on Mac. It's the default format for most basic rich text editors, like TextEdit. In addition to TextEdit, I've used Scrivener, Voodoopad and Notational Velocity; and Pages as a word processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *TextEdit* (included with OS X), it has support for `txt`, `rtf`, `rtfd` (with attachments, e.g. images), `odt` (OpenDocument from OpenOffice), and some support for `doc` and `docx`.

There's Microsoft Office for Mac, of course, with full support for `doc` and `docx` (macros might not work though, check the MS documentation). Word also supports `rtf` of course.

OpenOffice / LibreOffice / NeoOffice support `doc`/`docx` quite well too, AFAIK, but their native format is `odt`. They also support `rtf`.

Apple sells iWork with Pages, whose native format is `.pages`and incompatible with everything else.

---

There are a few other word processors with fewer users, like Mariner Write, but I don't know about their file format support.

Comment: iWorks default format is unique to it, but it can read and write doc and rtf files.